# Correct position of clauses in a multiple join

Tags: mysql

1. Is there a difference between the following two queries:

   ```
   select ...
   join table1 
   on condition1
   join table2
   on condition2
   ```

   and

   ```
   select ...
   join table1
   join table2
   on condition1
   and condition2
   ```
2. Does it depend on my table structure?

Answer (score 1):

the second is wrong , it will not work .  the first also wrong it must

```
   join table1 on condition1
   join table2 on condition2 

//-- no need to use `FROM`
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, i repaired my question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
select *
from   table1
       join tableA on condition1,
       table2
       join tableB on condition2
```

Comment: Thanks! My Question was this: [two-positions-of-on-clause-which-is-faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855702/two-positions-of-on-clause-which-is-faster)