# Two positions of ON clause: Which is faster?

Tags: mysql

Would it be faster to join a given select this way

```
select ...
join table1 
on condition1
join table2
on condition2
```

then this

```
select ...
join table1
join table2
on condition1
and condition2
```

because you keep the temp-tables smaller?

(Let us assume: condition1 has nothing to do with table2.)

Comment: They're different. The condition is used to join the tables, so `condition1` would just be a filter.

Comment: Your SQL is off.  You can't use JOIN without a table both before and after it.  Both of the examples seem wrong.

Comment: @mjuarez I think it was omitted for illustration.

Comment: Still depends on indexed fields, fields involved in conditions and the conditions themselves.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it´s like a filter. Can i force, that MySQL filter in a first step and join in a second? (Or should i filter in another way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, filter conditions should be stated "as soon as possible", that is, option 1 *may* perform better.

In practice, most of the time, the SQL parser will optimize either version to the same execution plan. That is, unless your conditions are really twisted, or `table1` or `table2` are actually subqueries.

If you have actual queries to play with, check the execution plan: `EXPLAIN [your query here]`

(sorry, it is hard to be more specific if you don't feed us with more... specifics)